# Problem with writting into a matrix in Mathematica

Tags: matrix

I have declared a matrix using

```
S = ConstantArray[0, {246,246}]
```

And when I try to write into it by a loop I get the following error "Tag Times in 0\ Null is Protected". The loop I'm using is the following:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 246, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 246, j++,
  Suma = 0;
  For[t = 1, t <= 5, t++,
    Suma = 
      Suma + (Xd[[i]][[t]] - Mean[Xd[[i]] ] )* (Xd[[j]][[t]] - 
          Mean[Xd[[j]] ]);
    ]
   S[[i]][[j]]=N[Suma/5];
  ]
 ]
```

I really don't get why I get this error since I can write into the matrix one by one by simply putting a value into `S[[1]][[1]]` for instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please provide the expression for `Xd` (or a simplified version of it), so that readers can experiment with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon just before the statement defining each piece of `S`. Once you fix that, your code will run. But before I close your question, I just wanted to point out that a triply nested `For` loop is an extremely convoluted way to go about this.

You didn't give us `Xd`, so let's pretend it is defined like this:

```
Xd = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {246, 5}];
```

You can get rid of the outermost `For` loops and the need to pre-create `S` by using `Table` instead, and have the benefit that this code actually returns the value of S rather than just creating it as a side-product:

```
S = Table[Module[{Suma = 0}, 
  For[t = 1, t <= 5, t++, 
   Suma = Suma + (Xd[[i]][[t]] - Mean[Xd[[i]]])*(Xd[[j]][[t]] - 
         Mean[Xd[[j]]]);] ; N[Suma/5]], {i, 246}, {j, 246}]
```

But we can do better than this in clarifying and shortening the code by noting that your innermost loop is just defining the dot product of the demeaned row and column of `Xd`. The following is massively faster (50 times on my machine) than either your example or my previous one, and the result is the same.

```
Table[N[(Xd[[i]] - Mean[Xd[[i]]]).(Xd[[j]] - Mean[Xd[[j]]])/5], 
 {i, 246}, {j, 246}]
```

Comment: Upvoted taking advantage that you haven't set the CW bit ;)

Comment: I'd meant to! Got distracted! Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, `MatrixPlot[S, ColorFunction -> ColorData["RedGreenSplit"]]` can be quite pretty using my specification.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has solved my problem!